# Can we use "later" for a future sense like this one: "I will start cooking a little later."

Tags: grammar, meaning, meaning-in-context, idiomatic-language, future-constructions

I know that we use **"in"** rather than **"later"** for future tense, such as **"I will graduate in 6 months"** rather than **"I will graduate 6 months later".**

But when it comes to **"a very short time"** in the future, I sometimes hear sentences such as:

1- **I will start cooking in a little bit.**

2- **I will start cooking a little later.**

But I am not quite sure whether they are idiomatic. Are they idiomatic?

Comment: Yes, a little later and in a little while [or bit]. You can look this stuff up before asking and might even find  you do not need to ask. :)

Comment: "I will start cooking a little later" is fine but might be ambiguous. It could mean "later than I had previously intended" rather "later than now" in some contexts. "in a little bit" is very idiomatic and definitely means in the future. "6 months later" does make sense if you know later than what. You are right that it is not a valid substitute for "in 6 months".

Comment: **"I will graduate in 6 months"** means 6 months from **now**, unless there is some further context that changes the meaning.  **"I will graduate 6 months later"** means 6 months **after** some other event which needs specifying.